# Cannot set Environment Variables - Apache 2.4.57 AlmaLinux

Tags: apache, environment

I have some issues to set the LANG environment variable to my apache webserver.

When I print out the configuration (using php_info()) at my php-File I get the following entries (for environment):

[image]

Regarding the fact, that it **should already been set** on the default service settings (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service):

```
# See httpd.service(8) for more information on using the httpd service.

# Modifying this file in-place is not recommended, because changes
# will be overwritten during package upgrades.  To customize the
# behaviour, run "systemctl edit httpd" to create an override unit.

# For example, to pass additional options (such as -D definitions) to
# the httpd binary at startup, create an override unit (as is done by
# systemctl edit) and enter the following:

#       [Service]
#       Environment=OPTIONS=-DMY_DEFINE

[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
Wants=httpd-init.service
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target httpd-init.service
Documentation=man:httpd.service(8)

[Service]
Type=notify
Environment=LANG=C  # <-----------------------------------

...
```

Even when I try to modify enviroment of the service with additional files like /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/xxx.conf:

```
[Service]
Environment="LANG=C"
#Environment=LANG=C
#Environment=ABC=C
#Environment="DEF=C"
#EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/httpd
```

The environment still just contains "USER" and "HOME".

Additional information:

```
httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (AlmaLinux)
Server built:   Jul 20 2023 00:00:00
```

ENV Apache Module is loaded:

```
[root@alma-master ~]# httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
...
env_module (shared)
...
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior was PHP-FPM (which seems to be a default module at recent linux versions) - in older version this module was not installed when I run
"*yum install php*"

All you have to do - set the parameter "clear_env" (default yes) to no.

/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:

```
clear_env = no
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use `SetEnv` in apache config file. Add in your config line like:

```
SetEnv LANG C
```

For more information you can visit apache [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv).

Comment: I have set this also - but this has no effect to Enviroment variables - I get this as a PHP Variable:

$_SERVER['LANG'] C

Comment: WHere did you set it? Did you load `mod_env` apache module?

Comment: Sorry for the delay: 

   '[root@alma-master ~]# httpd -M
   Loaded Modules:
   ...
   env_module (shared)
   ...'